# Load local JS file on a web page

Tags: javascript, firefox, scratchpad

I wanted to know if there's a way to load a JS file, located on my computer, on my browser.

I know it's possible with Firefox with Scratchpad, but could it be with Chrome or whatever else?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with Chrome/Chromium. You can store the file at `LocalFileSystem` using `webkitRequestFileSystem` and get a reference the file using `FileEntry.toURL()` which returns a `filesystem:` protocol URL.

Alternatively, use `<input type="file">` to upload the file object or folder and `URL.createObjectURL()` to reference the file as a `Blob URL`.